# how to get website content with xpath?

Tags: xpath

i want to check if the website uses schema.org tags. But with my script i get a empty result.

```
$sUrl = 'http://adresse.gelbeseiten.de/120002540061/alois-dallmayr-kg/muenchen/altstadt#gaststaetten-und-restaurants;originIndex=1;origin=/restaurant/muenchen';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHtmlFile($sUrl);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

$aLinks = array();
$vRes = $xpath->query('//text()[contains(.,"itemprop="streetAdress")]');
foreach ($vRes as $obj) {
    $aLinks[] = $obj->textContent;
}
print_r($aLinks);
```

Comment: There are no text values that contain "itemprop" in that web page, but quite a bunch of attributes with that name. What are you _really_ trying to do? I don't quite get your first sentence, even when re-translating it to German...

Comment: Didn't know about this standard yet. That's the cool thing on SO, you're often seeing new stuff... Now I'm getting what you want to do. They're not using schema.org templates though but some precedessor, data-vocabulary.org.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which you want to get exactly.

If you are going to get `<span id="inserat_addr_str" itemprop="street-address"> Dienerstr. 14-15</span>` using `itemprop` attribute, try use the following xpath (Id and text will also get you the element, but I assume you want to use `itemprop`)

```
$vRes = $xpath->query("//*[@itemprop='street-address']");
// $vRes = $xpath->query("//*[@id='inserat_addr_str']");
// $vRes = $xpath->query("//*[contains(text(), 'Dienerstr. 14-15')]");
```